# How set description to DAG tags in apache airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

Tags for DAG are created automatically. But is there a way to create meaningful description for the tag? So user can not only use tags for searching but see description of tags that are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag is just a string, it's not an entity of its own in Airflow. In [Airflow database](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/database-erd-ref.html) you only have `dag_tag <dag_id, name>` where you associate DAG with a tag. So no way to add description or any other metadata to the tag.